# Python - Win32com - Open Workbook & Create a New Excel File for Each Tab

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have an MS Excel Workbook that I would like to open and then loop through the tabs and create and save a workbook for each tab in the original workbook. So I open file A and there are tabs 1, 2, 3 and create and save a file B, C, D each with one a unique tab in it. I have the code for the VBA which creates a single copy of a worksheet but when I attempt to do this in Python I end up with all the tabs in each workbook. The following is the VBA that works:

---

```
 Sub ConvertTabsToFiles()
    Dim currPath As String
    currPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=currPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
 Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

---

The following is the Python Code that does not work:

---

```
 xlApp = win32.com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Inputfile.xlsx")

 for sheet in xlwb.Worksheets:
     sheet.Copy
     xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\\"+ sheet.Name+".xlsx")
```

---

Your help is really appreciated, I am stumped. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `sheet.Copy` is just a name, it doesn't do anything without being called...unless it's a property.

Comment: Thanks. How would I specify the exact worksheet I want to save if I can not use the name? Thanks

Comment: You'd need to create a new workbook for each `sheet`. I've never used the `win32com` stuff to do this, I've always used http://www.python-excel.org/. The idea is the same there though, open a new workbook, save a sheet, close book, save a different sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for Schollii, I was able to get on the right track. The following is what worked for me, I hope it helps you:

```
for sheet in xlwb.Worksheets:
     xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
     nwb = xlApp.WorkbookAdd()
     sheet.Copy(Before=nwb.Sheet(1))
     nwb.SaveAs("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\\" +sheet.Name+ ".xlsx")
     nwb.Close(True)
```

Thank you everyone. Especially Schollii for getting me on the right track. Also Thanks TankorSmash for the answer, too.

Comment: awesome. Dont' forget that the way to thank people on SO for the value of their post is to upvote their post.

Answer (score 5):

You can save individual sheets via the SaveAs method:

```
for sheet in xlwb.Worksheets:
     filename = r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\" + sheet.Name + ".xlsx"
     sheet.SaveAs(filename)
     print('Saved sheet to', filename)
```

Note I put the 'r' prefix to the string otherwise the backslashes get interpreted by Python as special characters unless doubled which obfuscates the string.

Comment: Schollii thanks that is exactly what I am attempting to do. I tried the code and it still saves a copy of the entire workbook and not just the individual tab/spreadsheet in the original.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be either a bug or a badly documented function, and I can't try it locally, unfortunately. See for example the second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940409/use-vba-macro-to-save-each-excel-worksheet-as-separate-workbook. Glad my post was of help  although it wasn't completely accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

for newer version of excel the codes changes from

xlApp.WorkbookAdd()

to

xlApp.Workbooks.Add()